# React State not available from Parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a form with a child  component that renders as a table.

```
ParentComponent extends React {

state = {
      anArray: []
}

<ParentComponent> 
   <table>
    map ( thing => <ChildComponent {someFunction= this.updateFunction;} />
```

When ChildComponent maps the data to individual TD's.  In my onChange in the ChildComponent, I'm invoking

```
 onChange = this.props.someFunction();
```

and the code is hitting my breakpoint which is great. It calls someFunction in the ParentComponent.  In someFunction, I'm trying to access the parent's state so I can match the onChanged TD with the proper index in the array but I'm getting undefined.

```
someFunction(id) {
  const index = this.state.anArray.findIndex( x => x.id === id) ;
  if (index === -1)
    // handle error
     console.log("DIDN'T FIND ID: " + id);
  });
}
```

Why wouldn't I have access to state on the function invocation from the ChildComponent?  I expected to be able to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from the posted code, but I guess you haven't bind the `someFunction` and you have the context of the child, instead of parent's.

```
ParentComponent extends React {

  constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this)
  }

  someFunction(){
    ...
  }

  render(){
      ...
  }

}
```

If you have the necessary babel plugins you can even do

```
ParentComponent extends React {

  someFunction = () => {
    ...
  }

  render(){
      ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Avraam, that worked.  I thought I didn't need to bind it.  Thank you!